# Filtered a query in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

To display some items from a post type, I'm using this WordPress query:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'realisations',
    'status'    => 'publish',
    'order'     => 'ASC'
));
```

But how can I filter the datas returned by this query depending the infos in the post type page ? For example, I have a input 'year' to get the year of the project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use wp_query like Below

```
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => array( 'realisations' ),
    'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ),
    'order'                  => 'ASC',
    'orderby'                => 'date',
    'year'                   => 'yourinputyear' // 2021
   );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                   echo get_the_title();
              endwhile;
}else{
        echo "Data not found";
    }
```

Please try this way. Hope is useful.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Date Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters) check below code.

```
$posts = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'realisations',
    'status'    => 'publish',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'date_query' => array(
        array( 'year' => 'yourinputyear' )
    )
) );
```